# Get a branch name from squashed commit of pull request

Tags: git, shell, github

How to get a branch name of a pull request when it is squash merged into my master branch? Tried `git branch --merged` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any of the popular web-based systems for managing pull requests, they're going to stick the branch name and pull request information in the log subject. You can then extract that like so:

```
$ git log --pretty="format:%s"
Add deploy procedure
Add release management documentation
Merged in feature/tkt-124/improve-changelog-output (pull request #334)
Merged in feature/tkt-128/clean-up-more-menu-item (pull request #331)
Merged in fix/tkt-113/disable-hyperlink (pull request #333)
```

This example is from a system using BitBucket to manage. GitHub and GitLab are similar. If you use your own home grown strategy, you may want to adopt a similar convention.

In the output here, the first two are *direct* commits to the master branch. The remaining three are merged PR, showing both the branch and the pull request number. You can use `awk` or similar text processing tools to extract the specific parts you want.

Comment: we are just using github to manage our git, but these doesn't seem to be standard, some messages have branch name and some do not have it

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's in the merge message you can't -- which is also true of recorded merges, but the native-git default message for a squash merge lists the individual commits not the branch-tip name.  Git branch names are repo-local anyway, not the right thing to tie to administrative records. Use a trailer on the commit message to do that is the usual way, commits can be "on" any number of branches.